# Change language of glossary output when using dualentry

Tags: glossaries, languages, acronyms

I'm writting a document in Spanish. I have the Glossary and Acronyms separated, when I print the acronyms, this is the output:

[image]

I would like to change "glossary" (the one in red) into "glosario".

I'm using the command `\newdualentry` like this:

```
\newdualentry{OMS} % label
 {OMS}            % abbreviation
 {Organización Mundial de la Salud}  % long form
 {Autoridad directiva y coordinadora en asuntos de sanidad internacional en el sistema de las Naciones Unidas} % description
```

The command is defined like this:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
 \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
  description={#6},#1
 }
 \makeglossaries
  \newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}
}
```

And the Acronym's list is printed like this:

```
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={\titulos{Siglas y Acrónimos}},toctitle={Siglas y Acrónimos},style=listhypergroup]
```

Also, the command is defined after the document language:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Just replace `see={[Glossary:]{gls-#3}}` with `see={[Glosario:]{gls-#3}}` in the definition of `\newdualentry` or replace the text with a markup command, such as `see={[\glossaryname:]{gls-#3}}`. Unrelated: `\makeglossaries` should be outside the definition of `\newdualentry`.

Answer (score 2):

(Converting my comment into an answer.) The English text has been hard-coded into the definition of `\newdualentry`. Just replace `Glossary` with `\glossaryname`. The `\makeglossaries` command should only be used once before all entries are defined, so that needs to be moved out of the definition of `\newdualentry`:

```
\makeglossaries
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
 \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
  description={#6},#1
 }%
  \newacronym[see={[\glossaryname:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}%
}
```